# Create pd.Series from Stockdata

Tags: pandas, series, stock

I'm trying to create a pd.Series from data with a date column and three columns of stock values. All I get is a Series with dates and 'NaN' as values?

The data looks like this

```
        Datum       Eroeffnung  Tief        Hoch        Schluss
0       31.12.69    100.0000    100.0000    100.0000    100.0000
1       30.01.70    94.2489     94.2489     94.2489     94.2489
2       27.02.70    96.9790     96.9790     96.9790     96.9790
...
6478    11.07.19    2205.346    2205.346    2205.346    2205.346
6479    12.07.19    2212.645    2212.645    2212.645    2212.645
6480    15.07.19    2214.340    2214.340    2214.340    2214.340
6481    16.07.19    2208.088    2208.088    2208.088    2208.088
6482    17.07.19    2197.936    2197.936    2197.936    2197.936
```

When I do the following:

```
data = pd.read_csv('msci_world_kurse_vers6.csv')

d = data['Datum'].astype('datetime64')
idx = pd.DatetimeIndex(data['Datum'])
s = data['Schluss'].astype(float)
s1 = pd.Series(data['Schluss'] index=data['Datum'])
s2 = pd.Series(s, index=idx)
s3 = pd.Series(s, index=d)
```

I get for s1, s2, s3:

```
Datum
1969-12-31   NaN
1970-01-30   NaN
1970-02-27   NaN
1970-03-31   NaN
1970-04-30   NaN
1970-05-29   NaN
1970-06-30   NaN
1970-07-31   NaN
1970-08-31   NaN
1970-09-30   NaN
1970-10-30   NaN
1970-11-30   NaN
```

Something like

```
plt.plot(data['Datum'], data['Schluss'])
```

is working well.

Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I think you want `DatetimeIndex`, so you can use parameters `index_col` and `parse_dates` in [`read_csv`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html):

```
data = pd.read_csv('msci_world_kurse_vers6.csv', index_col=['Datum'], parse_dates=['Datum'])
```

In your code get missing values, because data alignment, it means Series of index try match with new index and if indices are different, get missing values.

Solution is convert values to numpy array for avoid it:

```
#pandas 0.24+
s1 = pd.Series(data['Schluss'].to_numpy(), index=data['Datum'])
s2 = pd.Series(s.to_numpy(), index=idx)
s3 = pd.Series(s.to_numpy(), index=d)
```

---

```
s1 = pd.Series(data['Schluss'].values, index=data['Datum'])
s2 = pd.Series(s.values, index=idx)
s3 = pd.Series(s.values, index=d)
```

Comment: Damn, that's exactly where I've been looking for hours. Thx